# wamp server only 2/3 services running-windows could not start the wampmariadb64 service on local computer-process terminated with error 1067

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mariadb, wamp

Apache and MySQL services are running but MariaDB service is not starting.

1. I tried starting the MariaDB service by going to the
   wamp icon-> MariaDB -> service administration 'wampmariadb64'-> Start/resume service.
2. I also tried to start the service by going to the
   task manager ->services -> wampmariadb64
   but it showed the error 1067(process terminated unexpectedly).
3. When I installed the wamp server a dilouge box appeared saying mysql_install_db.exe stopped unexpectedly.

Wamp icon is orange but when I uncheck allow mariadb by cliking on
wamp icon->wamp settings->uncheck mariadb.
Wamp icon is turning green from orange.
How can I solve this issue? Please try to help.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Do you want to use mariaDB?

Comment: You should probably start by reading `mariadb_mysql.txt` found in the wamp folder

Comment: Did you start the install using the "Run as Administrator" option? If not, uninstall, delete the `wamp` or `wamp64` folder and then install again using it

Comment: Yeah i have installed the wamp server using "Run as Administrator" .

Comment: Check back in the Windows Event Log to when you installed and see what error actually occured

Comment: Error 1067 = ER_INVALID_DEFAULT. Would be more useful to get the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...so,first of all, I'm a beginner in WebDev and I was struggling with this issue for approx. 6-7 days. Everytime, it didn't go green, I tried uninstalling and installing it, it would work well on 1st go, but whenever I open my laptop next day and start the wampserver, it would stick on being orange and I was definitely sick of it...I tried almost everything, changing the port number from 80 to something else as in some cases where people had skype opened which occupied port 80 but I had no skype in my laptop, so it wasn't the issue in mine, allowing access by going in Task Manager and many other things which I don't even remember as I did whatever was written in different solutions in the hope that maybe a single solution can work for me and guess what I found my solution in your answer.
when I unchecked allow MariaDB by clicking on the wamp icon. wamp icon->wamp settings->uncheck MariaDB. Wamp icon turned green from orange but MariaDB was not working, so I again went in wamp settings and checked Allow MariaDB and now MariaDB is also working and symbol also turned green and I am able to open phpMyAdmin too. So, thanks. U can try it too.